# parametrisation of sphere

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

The sphere given by $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2,$ its parametric repression is given by
$$ \Phi(u,v)= \left(r \sin u \cos v, r \sin u \sin v, r \cos u \right), \quad  (u,v)\in [0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi].$$ (This seems to be standard). (I'm curious to know why the range of $u$ and $v$ differs)

> My question is: in the above parametrisation can we tale the range of $(u, v)\in [0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi] $? if so, what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you remember regular spherical coordinates and why the angles have different ranges?

Comment: @NM: thanks for the hint. but I'm unable to catch it, can you explain  a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Start with cylindrical coordinates

$$\begin{cases}x = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta \\ z = z \end{cases}$$

which is a polar coordinates substitution in the $xy$ plane. The way one retrieves spherical coordinates from cylindrical is by the further "polar polar" coordinates substitution

$$\begin{cases}r = \rho\sin\phi \\ z = \rho\cos\phi \end{cases}$$

in the $rz$ plane. However, the $rz$ plane differs from the $xy$ plane because it is only a half plane. By definition, the radial coordinate of a polar substitution must be strictly positive. Thus the angular restriction is to accommodate this restriction to the right half plane where $\sin\phi \geq 0$